# Getting my head around ALUs

Tags: alu

What is a good place to start understanding about ALU's?

Lots of sites seem very over the top and complex, can anyone recommend a good place to start?

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: What aspects of ALU are you interested in?

Comment: @jippie the whole ENA ENB etc like got a few questions here asking for what conditions will output be A or B or bitwise inversion of A etc

Comment: Is it a specific processor?

Comment: @jippie No in general, just for personal interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest that you go to Google and enter the search terms **74HC181 datasheet**. Access one of the many links to retreive the data sheet. Study this relatively simple logic circuit that provides a 4-bit ALU function.

Wikipedia also has a [concise page about ALU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit).